# StackOverflow Error on vending machine

Tags: java

I wrote a vending machine program for my class final but I keep getting a Stack Overflow Error. 
I believe it has something to do with the inheritance but not sure, i've tried changing that around with no help.

Any help from you guys would be immensely appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my program:

```
package vendingmachine;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VendingMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VendMachine freestyle = new VendMachine();
        int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to use the vending        machine?", "Vending Machine",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.exit(selectedOption);
        } else {
            freestyle.offerChoice();
        }
    }
}

class VendMachine {
    Snacks temp = new Snacks();
    private float moneyPaid = 0;
    int maxBevCount = 50;
    int maxSnackCount = 100;
    float itemPrice = .65f;
    private final String coke = "Coke Zero";
    private final String sprite = "Sprite Zero";
    private final String water = "Dasani";
    private float moneyReturned = 0;
    private int ask;
    NumberFormat formating = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public void offerChoice() {
        ask = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like a Snack: 1 or  Beverage: 2 ", "Vending Machine",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
        if (ask == 1) {
            temp.askUser();
        } else {
            int askBevType = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of beverage would you like? " + coke + ": 1 " + sprite
                    + ": 2 " + water + ": 3 " + "Quit: 4 ", "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
            switch (askBevType) {
            case 1: {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you chose " + coke + " the price is: " + formating.format(itemPrice));
                addMoney();
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you chose " + sprite + " the price is: " + formating.format(itemPrice));
                addMoney();
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you chose " + water + " the price is: " + formating.format(itemPrice));
                addMoney();
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public float addMoney() {
        moneyPaid = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " insert your money", "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
        while (true) {
            if (moneyPaid == itemPrice) {
                vend();
            }
            if (moneyPaid < itemPrice) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "that's not enough... please insert more money!", "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                float moreCashIn = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The items cost " + formating.format(itemPrice)
                        + " insert your money.", "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
                if (moreCashIn >= itemPrice) {
                    vend();
                }
            } else if (moneyPaid > itemPrice) {
                moneyReturned = moneyPaid - itemPrice;
                vend();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "And here is your change of " + formating.format(moneyReturned), "Vending Machine",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            return moneyPaid;
        }
    }

    public void vend() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vending........Here you go. Have a nice day!", "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        restock();
    }

    public void restock() {
        if (ask == 2) {
            maxBevCount -= 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Beverage Stock in the machine is now " + maxBevCount, "Vending Machine",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            maxBevCount += 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Machine is now restocked with " + maxBevCount + " Beverages ", "Vending Machine",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            maxSnackCount -= 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stock in the machine is now " + maxSnackCount, "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            maxSnackCount += 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Machine is now restocked with " + maxSnackCount + " items", "Vending Machine",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

class Snacks extends VendMachine {
    int askSnackType;
    EmAndM emAndM = new EmAndM("M&M's", 180, 1.80f);
    Snickers snickers = new Snickers("Snickers", 280, 2.50f);
    Gum gum = new Gum("Gum", 110, 1.25f);
    Popcorn popcorn = new Popcorn("Popcorn", 190, 2.30f);
    Crackers crackers = new Crackers("Crackers", 130, 1.90f);
    Chips chips = new Chips("Chips", 140, 1.70f);

    public void askUser() {
        askSnackType = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like some- " + emAndM.name + ": 1 " + snickers.name + ": 2 "
                + gum.name + ": 3 " + popcorn.name + ": 4 " + crackers.name + ": 5 " + chips.name + ": 6 " + " Quit: 7 ", "Vending Machine",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
        switch (askSnackType) {
        case 1: {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You chose " + emAndM.name + " , Calories: " + emAndM.calories + " the price is: " + formating.format(emAndM.price));
            addMoney();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You chose " + snickers.name + " , Calories: " + snickers.calories + " the price is: " + formating.format(snickers.price));
            addMoney();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You chose " + gum.name + " , Calories: " + gum.calories + " the price is: " + formating.format(gum.price));
            addMoney();
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You chose " + popcorn.name + " , Calories: " + popcorn.calories + " the price is: " + formating.format(popcorn.price));
            addMoney();
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You chose " + crackers.name + " , Calories: " + crackers.calories + " the price is: " + formating.format(crackers.price));
            addMoney();
            break;
        }
        case 6: {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You chose " + chips.name + " , Calories: " + chips.calories + " the price is: " + formating.format(chips.price));
            addMoney();
            break;
        }
        case 7: {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    class SugarySnacks {}

    class EmAndM extends Snacks {
        String name;
        int calories;
        float price;

        EmAndM(String brand, int cal, float cost) {
            name = brand;
            calories = cal;
            price = cost;
        }
    }

    class Snickers extends Snacks {
        String name;
        int calories;
        float price;

        Snickers(String brand, int cal, float cost) {
            name = brand;
            calories = cal;
            price = cost;
        }
    }

    class Gum extends Snacks {
        String name;
        int calories;
        float price;

        Gum(String brand, int cal, float cost) {
            name = brand;
            calories = cal;
            price = cost;
        }
    }

    class SaltySnacks {}

    class Popcorn extends Snacks {
        String name;
        int calories;
        float price;

        Popcorn(String brand, int cal, float cost) {
            name = brand;
            calories = cal;
            price = cost;
        }
    }

    class Crackers extends Snacks {
        String name;
        int calories;
        float price;

        Crackers(String brand, int cal, float cost) {
            name = brand;
            calories = cal;
            price = cost;
        }
    }

    class Chips extends Snacks {
        String name;
        int calories;
        float price;

        Chips(String brand, int cal, float cost) {
            name = brand;
            calories = cal;
            price = cost;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Stacktrace will list the method that is causing the overflow.

Comment: You need to format your posted code better.  I am not doing to debug your program for you, but I will give you a hint.  The 'stack' is the series of methods which have been called.  Each time a method is called, it is added to the top of the stack, when it finished, it is removed.  If the method A calls another method B, then B will be placed on top of A in the stack.  If B calls yet another method C, then it is placed on top of B.  You get an overflow when you have too many calls on the stack.  So see if you can tell where methods are being called (added) but never end (removed).

Comment: I highly recommend making use of consistent indentation to make the code more human-readable.

Comment: `class SugarySnacks {}` Love this

Comment: I thought about editing this, but the time it takes would not be worth the two points

Comment: Gum extends Snacks, Snacks extends VendMachine. A Snack is a kind of a vending machine (but not a VendingMachine; that's a separate class from VendMachine).

Comment: yeah i tried to edit it with 4 spaces like it said. sorry still new at this. but im trying. haha I will try to use the stacktrace method and see if I can spot the one that never ends.

Comment: Solved my issue, in my VendMachine class i had created temp object in the Snack class. this was causing the Stack overflow. I fixed the problem by creating the same temp object in the offerChoice Method. Thanks for giving me a push to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, in my VendMachine class i had created temp object in the Snack class. this was causing the Stack overflow. I fixed the problem by creating the same temp object in the offerChoice Method.

Here's the modified area:

class VendMachine {

```
Snacks temp = new Snacks();**//removed this object**
private float moneyPaid = 0;
int maxBevCount = 50;
int maxSnackCount = 100;
float itemPrice = .65f;
private final String coke = "Coke Zero";
private final String sprite = "Sprite Zero";
private final String water = "Dasani";
private float moneyReturned = 0;
private int ask;
NumberFormat formating = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public void offerChoice(){
    Snacks temp = new Snacks(); **//Inserted same object under this method**
    ask = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like a Snack: 1 or Beverage: 2 ", "Vending Machine", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
    if (ask == 1){

        temp.askSnackType();
```